# git error: could not commit config file /home/vagrant/.gitconfig

Tags: git

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on a virtual machine.
I wrote a bash script, in the script, I want to set some global git configuration:

```
git config --global xxx vvv
```

when I run the script first time, it's working correctly, afterwards, no matter how many times I run the script, I always got the error:

```
error: could not commit config file /home/vagrant/.gitconfig
```

But strangely, if I run the same command manually in shell, it's working fine again.

Comment: Could there be a permissions issue at work here?  What permissions does the bash script have and then what permissions do you have from the shell?

Comment: the script permission is 777,  my user(vagrant) is admin

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761284/git-error-could-not-commit-config-file).

Comment: What else does the script do?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I saw that thread, but it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @TomBarron, basically the script is to do proxy setting for various applications: git, npm, pip

Comment: Mull over the script and see whether something could be locking that file.

Comment: Does the script change user identity? Are 'xxx' and 'vvv' static or do they change from run to run? You could try check whether ~/.gitconfig is writable just before issuing the git command.

Comment: @TomBarron, it's static, ~/.gitconfig is writable. I think it's very easy to reproduce.