# error: could not commit config file /usr2/c_vkpanw/.gitconfig

Tags: git

I am trying to setup my git  config but I am getting below error , please help me to solve this error

```
$ set +o history
$ touch ~/.gitcookies
$ chmod 0600 ~/.gitcookies
$ git config --global http.cookiefile ~/.gitcookies
```

error: could not commit config file /usr2/c_vkpanw/.gitconfig

Comment: Did `git config` produce the error about commit? Hard to believe. You need to show us all commands you've run.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

- the `~/.gitconfig` file is writable
- there is no other processes keeping an handle/lock on it, as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18761583/6309).